# Find cell row with 2 criteria

Tags: excel, vba, find, criteria

Is it possible to find a row with 2 criteria?
I'm importing survey anwsers to a worksheet, now I want to find the answers of a specified person
I need to find the row in the **worksheet(ImportLimesurvey)** that has 2 specified cell values:

In that row:

- the value of the C-cell has to be one of the highest value in that column (I used the function `Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(rng)`)

This value means how much of the survey is filled in. The highest value stands in multiple answer-rows. The highest value is different for every survey. (example, if a survey has 7 pages and the participant fills in all pages :the highest value is 7 for that person, but if the person didn't complete that survey, the value could be e.g. 3), So the filter of the highest value is if the participant completed the whole survey.

- the value of the L-cell has to be the same as the cell **(Worksheets("Dataimport").Range("M2")**

M2= accountnumber of the person I need the answers from

The correct row has to be pasted to (Worksheets("Dataimport").Range("A7")

This is my current code:

```
Dim g As Range
Dim rng As Range
Set rng = Worksheets("ImportLimesurvey").Range("C:C")

d = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(rng)

With Worksheets("ImportLimesurvey").Range("L:L")
    Set g = .Find(Worksheets("Dataimport").Range("M2"), LookIn:=xlValues)
    g.Activate
End With
e = Range("C" & (ActiveCell.Row))
If e = d Then
ActiveCell.EntireRow.Copy _
Destination:=Worksheets("Dataimport").Range("A7")
End If
```

The problem here is that he finds the row with the right account number, but the answer with the C-value isn't always the highest. It picks (logically) just the first row with that accountnumber. So how can I find the row that matches those 2 criteria?

Thanks in advance

P.S. I'm new to VBA so I tried to be as specific as possible but if you need any additional info, just ask for it ;)

Comment: Are you able to provide some sample data? I'm wanting to clear up a few things before I tackle an answer; How many rows are there in your data set typcially, on average how many account numbers would be included in the data set, is the target account number appearing randomly throughout the data or all grouped together (if multiple rows for the same number)?

Comment: Probably the best way would be with Find/Find Next. On the first find, save the value from C-cell to a variable as well as the row number to a variable. Then proceed to `FindNext` every instance of the person. At each instance, check the C-cell value against your stored one to see if it's bigger. If it is, replace it with this new one and replace the stored row number to the new one. Keep going until all instances are done and you will have the row you want. Otherwise you could do a `For` Loop which to me is easier and you could pull the data into an array to make it fast.

Comment: @SamuelEverson the surveys stay open and a new answer-row comes everytime with a new participant/customer. So it keeps expending maybe in 10 years I have 1000 rows.

the acc°nr is a random generated number per customer. But if someone answered the question again, because it wasn't finished previously and had to start over. It has the same accnr° as previous unfinished answers. 
the same accnr° won't be grouped. The row is defined by the time of answering. So if you answer 10 days after your first answer. it might be possible that there are answers between your 2 answers.

Answer (score 0):

dmt32 forom mrexcel.com found a solution.

Link to topic: https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/find-row-with-2-criteria.1157983/

His code works fine:

```
Sub FindMaxValue()
    Dim FoundCell   As Range, rng As Range
    Dim MaxValue    As Long
    Dim Search      As String, FirstAddress As String
    Dim wsDataImport As Worksheet, wsImportLimesurvey As Worksheet
   
    With ThisWorkbook
        Set wsDataImport = .Worksheets("Dataimport")
        Set wsImportLimesurvey = .Worksheets("ImportLimesurvey")
    End With
   
    Search = wsDataImport.Range("M2").Value
    If Len(Search) = 0 Then Exit Sub
   
    With wsImportLimesurvey
   
        Set FoundCell = .Range("L:L").Find(Search, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
        If Not FoundCell Is Nothing Then
            FirstAddress = FoundCell.Address
            Do
               
                With FoundCell.Offset(, -9)
                    If .Value > MaxValue Then Set rng = FoundCell: MaxValue = .Value
                End With
               
                Set FoundCell = .Range("L:L").FindNext(FoundCell)
                If FoundCell Is Nothing Then Exit Do
            Loop Until FoundCell.Address = FirstAddress
           
            rng.EntireRow.Copy wsDataImport.Range("A7")
            MsgBox Search & Chr(10) & "Record Copied", 64, "Match Found"
           
        Else
            MsgBox Search & Chr(10) & "Record Not Found", 48, "Not Found"
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Still thanks for the tips.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, [Visual Basic conceptual topics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/visual-basic-conceptual-topics) is a great read to help in writing 'better' code. The biggest thing I encourage is to use meaningful variable names.

It's much easier to understand your code when you have variable names like `HighestCount` or `TargetSheet` etc. rather than names like `a` or `b` etc.

---

The answer to your question is yes.

I would write something like this:

```
Option Explicit

Public Function HighestSurveyRow(ByVal TargetAccountNumber As Long) As Long

    Dim ImportLimeSurveySheet As Worksheet
    Set ImportLimeSurveySheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("ImportLimeSurvey")
    
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim TargetRow As Long
    Dim SurveyCountArray As Variant
    Dim ArrayCounter As Long
    
    With ImportLimeSurveySheet
        ArrayCounter = 1
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 12).End(xlUp).Row
        ReDim SurveyCountArray(1 To LastRow, 1 To 2)
        For TargetRow = 1 To LastRow
            If .Cells(TargetRow, 12).Value = TargetAccountNumber Then
                SurveyCountArray(ArrayCounter, 2) = TargetRow
                SurveyCountArray(ArrayCounter, 1) = .Cells(TargetRow, 3).Value
                ArrayCounter = ArrayCounter + 1
            End If
        Next TargetRow
    End With
    
    Dim ResultArray(1 To 2) As Variant
    Dim ArrayElement As Long
    
    For ArrayElement = 1 To UBound(SurveyCountArray, 1)
        If SurveyCountArray(ArrayElement, 1) > ResultArray(1) Then
            ResultArray(1) = SurveyCountArray(ArrayElement, 1)
            ResultArray(2) = SurveyCountArray(ArrayElement, 2)
        End If
    Next ArrayElement
    
    HighestSurveyRow = ResultArray(1)

End Function

Sub FindRowForSurveyResults()
 
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("DataImport")
        .Range("A7").Value = HighestSurveyRow(.Range("M2").Value)
    End With

End Sub
```

It's split into a `Function` and a `Subroutine`. The Function executes most of the code and returns the row number. The Sub calls this function and writes this returned value to cell A7 on "DataImport".

The sub can be broken down as follows;

1. Using a with statement helps reduce code clutter of defining the worksheet twice.
2. The only thing the sub is doing is assigning a value to cell A7. To get the value it calls the function and assigns the parameter `TargetAccountNumber` as the value from cell M2.

The function can be broken down into the following steps;

1. All variables are declared and the target worksheet for the function is set.
2. The `LastRow` of column L is found to establish our maximum length of the Array and search range.
3. The Loop searches from Row 1 to the `LastRow` and compares the values from column L. If it matches the `TargetAccountNumber` parameter then the column C value and the row number are stored into the Array.
4. Once the Loop is done, another Loop is run to find the highest number. The first iteration will always store the first row's data. Each iteration after that compares the values stored in the `SurveyCountArray` with the current value of `ResultArray(1)` and if the value is greater, `ResultArray(1)` is updated with the value, `ResultArray(2)` is updated with the Row number.
5. Once the 2nd loop is done, the Row in `ResultArray(2)` is assigned to the function for the Sub to write to the worksheet.

It can definately be improved and refined to work faster and more efficiently, especially if you have a very large data set, but this should help get you thinking about ways you can use loops and arrays to find data.

Note: There *could* be duplicate rows for the outcome (say a user submits the same survey 3 times with the same answers), which I haven't tested for - I think this code would return the highest row number that matches the required criteria but could be tweaked to throw an error or message or even write all row numbers to the sheet.